# Flux not subscribing in Spring 5 reactor

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I'm probably missing something but I can't figure out what it is.

The following code does nothing at all:

```
webClient.get().uri("/some/path/here").retrieve()
     .bodyToMono(GetLocationsResponse.class)
     .doOnNext(System.out::println)
     .subscribe();
```

If I try to block the call it works fine:

```
webClient.get().uri("/some/path/here").retrieve()
      .bodyToMono(GetLocationsResponse.class)
      .doOnNext(System.out::println)
      .block();
```

The weird thing is that if I create a Flux "manually" (i.e not coming from the spring webClient) this works fine:

```
Flux.just("1", "2", "3")
    .filter(s -> !s.equals("2"))
    .doOnNext(System.out::println)
    .subscribe();
```

Could someone please explain what it is that I am doing wrong? Isn't `.subscribe()` supposed to execute the operation in the first case, just like it did in the last?

Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Short Answer**

`subscribe` does not block current thread, that means app main thread can complete earlier than Flux emits any element. So either use `block` or employ waiting in the main thread.

**Details**

Call to the no-args [subscribe()](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#subscribe--) just makes `request(unbounded)` on `Flux` without setting up any `Subscriber`. It triggers operation generally in a *separate thread* but *does not block the current thread*. Most likely, your main thread ends before `WebClient` received the response in that separate thread and [passive side effect `doOnNext(...)`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#doOnNext-java.util.function.Consumer-) happened.

To illustrate/test that operation is started, wait for some time in the main thread. Just put the following line right after `subscribe()` call:

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

Now, after playing with the timeout value, you'll be able to see result printed.

Let's now implicitly ship a custom `Scheduler` for async operations and wait for all its tasks to be completed. Also, let's pass the `System.out::println` as `subscribe(...)` argument instead of `doOnNext`, so that complete code appears as follows:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(); 

webClient.get().uri("/some/path/here").retrieve()
    .bodyToMono(GetLocationsResponse.class)
    .publishOn(Schedulers.fromExecutor(executor)) // next operation will go to this executor
    .subscribe(System.out::println); //still non-blocking

executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS); //block current main thread
```

This example uses slightly different [subscribe(Consumer)](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#subscribe-java.util.function.Consumer-). Most importantly, it adds [publishOn(Scheduler)](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#publishOn-reactor.core.scheduler.Scheduler-) which is backed by `ExecutorService`. The latter is used then to wait for termination in the main thread.

Surely, the much easier way to achieve the same result is to use `block()` as you mentioned initially:

> ```
> webClient.get().uri("/some/path/here").retrieve()
>       .bodyToMono(GetLocationsResponse.class)
>       .doOnNext(System.out::println)
>       .block();
> ```

Finally, note on your third example with `Flux.just(...)...subscribe()` - seems it just quickly completes before your main thread gets terminated. That's because it requires way less time to emit a few `String` elements compared to the emission of a single `GetLocationsResponse` element (implying timings for write request+read response+parse into POJO). However, if you make this `Flux` to delay elements, you'll get the same behavior reproduced:

```
Flux.just("1", "2", "3")
    .filter(s -> !s.equals("2"))
    .delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(500)) //this makes it stop printing in main thread
    .doOnNext(System.out::println)
    .subscribe(); 


Flux.just("1", "2", "3")
    .filter(s -> !s.equals("2"))
    .delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(500))
    .doOnNext(System.out::println)
    .blockLast(); //and that makes it printing back again
```