# How to simulate a delay in a Spring reactive stack thread

Tags: spring, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I am building two Spring versions of a single simple application. One of them is a Servlet stack and the other is a Reactive one. My goal is to show that the Reactive stack doesn't block threads from processing other requests when it's waiting for something else.
So, I simulate a delay in the code in both versions. However, the reactive stack seems to not handle other requests when the delay is taking effect. In other words, it's not being reactive, am I doing something wrong? Have I misunderstood the way Spring reactive works? I am simulating the delay incorrectly?

The reactive stack handler class

```
@Component @RequiredArgsConstructor
public class GradeHandler {
    private final GradeRepository gradeRepository;

    public Mono<ServerResponse> gradeHandler(ServerRequest serverRequest){
        String id = serverRequest.pathVariable("id");
        return ServerResponse.
                ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).
                body(getGradeByIdDelayed(id, Duration.ofSeconds(1)), Grade.class);
    }

    public Mono<ServerResponse> gradeHandler_blocking(ServerRequest serverRequest){
        String id = serverRequest.pathVariable("id");
        return ServerResponse.
                ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).
                body(getGradeByIdDelayed(id, Duration.ofSeconds(10000)), Grade.class);
    }

    private Mono<Grade> getGradeByIdDelayed(String id, Duration duration) {
        return gradeRepository.
                findById(id).
                delayElement(duration);
    }

}
```

The reactive stack router config file

```
@Configuration
public class GradeRouterConfig {
    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> gradeRouter(GradeHandler gradeHandler){
        return RouterFunctions.
                route(GET("grade/{id}").
                        and(accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)), gradeHandler::gradeHandler).
                andRoute(GET("blocking/grade/{id}").
                        and(accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)), gradeHandler::gradeHandler_blocking);
    }
}
```

The repository

```
@Repository
public interface GradeRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<Grade, String> {
}
```

The entity

```
@Document @Data @RequiredArgsConstructor @Builder
public class Grade {
    @Id
    private final String id;
    private final double grade;
    private final String studentName;
}
```

This is the client JavaScript code that calls the endpoints

```
gradesToBeQuried = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

var t0 = performance.now()

function httpGetAsync(theUrl, callback)
{
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onload = () => callback(xmlHttp.responseText);
    xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, true); // true for asynchronous
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}

function getRandomGradeId(grades) {
    return grades[Math.floor(Math.random() * grades.length)];
}

function getURLWithRandomGradeID(grades){
    randomGradeId = getRandomGradeId(grades);
    return "http://localhost:8080/grade/" + randomGradeId;
}

function getURLWithRandomGradeID_blocking(grades){
    randomGradeId = getRandomGradeId(grades);
    return "http://localhost:8080/blocking/grade/" + randomGradeId;
}

function checkFinishConditionAndLog(currentIndex, totalNumberOfQueries) {
    if (currentIndex === totalNumberOfQueries - 1) {
        var t1 = performance.now()
        console.log("it took " + (t1 - t0) / 1000 + " seconds.")
    }
}

function queryGrade(currentIndex, totalNumberOfQueries){
    let urlWithRandomGradeID = getURLWithRandomGradeID(gradesToBeQuried);
    httpGetAsync(urlWithRandomGradeID, (result) => {
        console.log(currentIndex + result);
        checkFinishConditionAndLog(currentIndex, totalNumberOfQueries);
    })
}

function queryGrade_blocking(){
    let urlWithRandomGradeID = getURLWithRandomGradeID_blocking(gradesToBeQuried);
    httpGetAsync(urlWithRandomGradeID, (result) => console.log("blocking thread is done"))
}

function runQueries(){
    const totalNumberOfQueries = 1000;
    const totalNumberOfBlockingQueries = 15;

    Array(totalNumberOfBlockingQueries).fill().map((_, i) => queryGrade_blocking());
    Array(totalNumberOfQueries).fill().map((_, i) => queryGrade(i, totalNumberOfQueries));
}

runQueries();
```

Comment: Do you run Javascript from browser? It's possible that you run into some browser limitation. I suggest running the test script with Node Js (or any other server side language). That might give you better results.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61551382/webflux-only-allowing-6-connections-for-the-api

Comment: @MartinTarjányi Yes, you are right. However, that is not my question, it's related to the fact that when the thread is blocked by the artificial delay command, it doesn't handle other requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much research I came across this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52375697/flux-not-subscribing-in-spring-5-reactor), it turns out that the `delayElement` function blocks the thread.